# CSS: Angles on a button

Tags: html, css

I have basic square buttons in my application:

[image]

I'd like to style the collection of buttons like this:

[image]

I don't know how you would get the angle at the top of each bar. Current square button CSS:

```
   .button {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 1;
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      transition: background-color 0.25s ease-out, color 0.25s ease-out;
      vertical-align: middle;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 0;
      padding: 0.85em 1em;
      margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
      font-size: 0.9rem;
      background-color: #2199e8;
      color: #fefefe; }
      [data-whatinput='mouse'] .button {
        outline: 0; }

.button.tiny {
    font-size: 0.6rem; }
```

Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: It's not easy to make normal elements just be missing a part of them like that without either using SVGs or a canvas, but you could possibly put an element *over* the top of the buttons to obscure them like that, giving the same effect. Otherwise I'd recommend SVGs.

Comment: will formalize later, but the messy version: http://dabblet.com/gist/f4ce2d82acf63941501951364721ff66

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this with using [transparent borders [CSS Tricks]](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/). The basics behind making this triangle design are this:

```css
.stack{
    float:left;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
.blank{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
.block{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.tri{
    width: 0px;
    height 0px;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid blue;
    border-bottom: 20px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="stack">
    <div class="blank"></div>
    <div class="blank"></div>
    <div class="tri"></div>
</div>
<div class="stack">
    <div class="blank"></div>
    <div class="tri"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="stack">
    <div class="tri"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Each `.stack` floats left, and the `div`s within all stay as `display:block` for stacking
As you create more columns, you'll need to stack more `.blank`s above and `.block`s below to account for your increase.
An improvement you can make to my code is to account for the 2px spacing margin and how that offsets your slope as a straight line.

This isn't to say its the only solution for this design, but its one that I think you can start with and improve upon as you learn more.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making them out of multiple pieces, you can define each button as a single button, and just position the labels onto them.

Note that, for ease of maintenance (and setup), this implementation makes heavy use of CSS variables. IE, Microsoft Edge, and Opera Mini do not (currently) support them ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) circa Jan 2017).

One downside of this method is the difficulty in getting a non-solid-color for the background, as you need to designate all borders *except for the right one* as transparent. That should be accomplishable via SVG, but a simple gradient is not going to be possible without it. Another is that any outline effect (`outline`, `box-shadow`, etc) will not "respect" the trapezoidal shape, and will instead draw around the entire rectangle.

Additionally, the first button's clickable area is somewhat small from a UX standpoint. I leave solving that to the user.

```css
.btnset{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    align-items:flex-end;
    
    /*Button Sizing*/
    --height-per: 36px; /*how much the height grows by the position*/
    --width-per: 75px; /*width of each bar*/
    
    /*Label Positioning*/
    --bottom-prc: 0.45; /*Percentage of height to offset label*/
    --bottom-offset: 19px; /*flat modifier to offset*/
    --bottom-first-offset: 15px; /*offset for first button*/
    --left-prc: 0.45;  /*Percentage of width to offset label*/
    --left-offset: 0px; /*flat modifier to offset*/
    --left-first-offset: 9px; /*offset for first button*/
    
    /*Coloration and Font Sizing*/
    --bgc: #000;
    --font-color: #fff;
    --font-size: 12pt;
    
    /*Hover Effects*/
    --hover-grow: 15px;
    --hover-bgc: #333;
}

.btnset button{
    --btn-num: 1; /*used to scale the later buttons*/
    --heightmod: 0px; /*used for hover effect*/
    
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    
    margin-right:1px;
    
    /*unset button defaults*/
    padding:0;
    width: 0;
    background:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    
    /*Creates the triangular top part*/
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent var(--bgc) transparent transparent ;
    border-width: var(--height-per) var(--width-per) 0 0;
    
    /*Creates the vertical bar part*/
    height: calc(calc(var(--height-per) * var(--btn-num)) + var(--heightmod));
    
    /*Hover Effects*/
    margin-top:var(--hover-grow);/*placeholder for the hover growth*/
    transition:300ms ease all;
}
.btnset button div{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    
    color: var(--font-color);
    font-size: var(--font-size);
    
    /*Scales the button label's position based on the button's visible size*/
    bottom: calc(calc(calc(var(--height-per) * var(--btn-num)) * var(--bottom-prc)) - var(--bottom-offset));
    left: calc(calc(var(--width-per) * var(--left-prc)) + var(--left-offset));
}
.btnset button:hover{
    --heightmod:var(--hover-grow); 
    margin-top:0px; 
    border-right-color: var(--hover-bgc); 
}

/*Instances. First one has different label offsets, rest just need to know their number*/
.btnset button:nth-child(1){
    --btn-num: 1;
    --left-offset: var(--left-first-offset);
    --bottom-offset: var(--bottom-first-offset);
}
.btnset button:nth-child(2){ --btn-num: 2; }
.btnset button:nth-child(3){ --btn-num: 3; }
.btnset button:nth-child(4){ --btn-num: 4; }
.btnset button:nth-child(5){ --btn-num: 5; }
.btnset button:nth-child(6){ --btn-num: 6; }
.btnset button:nth-child(7){ --btn-num: 7; }
.btnset button:nth-child(8){ --btn-num: 8; }
.btnset button:nth-child(9){ --btn-num: 9; }
```

```html
<div class="btnset">
    <button onclick="alert(this.firstElementChild.innerHTML);"><div>1</div></button>
    <button onclick="alert(this.firstElementChild.innerHTML);"><div>2</div></button>
    <button onclick="alert(this.firstElementChild.innerHTML);"><div>3</div></button>
    <button onclick="alert(this.firstElementChild.innerHTML);"><div>4</div></button>
    <button onclick="alert(this.firstElementChild.innerHTML);"><div>5</div></button>
    <button onclick="alert(this.firstElementChild.innerHTML);"><div>6</div></button>
</div>
```

Alternatively, an early version of this is available [on dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/f4ce2d82acf63941501951364721ff66)